# Sample Size of Random Sampling for Bad and Good Samples

Tags: decision-tree, sampling, random, supervised-learning, sample-size

I have a very large data set now. The response variable is binary 1/0. The bad population size is a very small portion of the entire data set. The good population size is 8,000,000. The bad population size that is tagged as 1 is only 7,000.

I used a decision tree, this decision tree would take the features as the inputs, and then would classify the individuals into either 1 or 0.

Because the population size was really large. R was not able to efficiently process all data. So I decided to randomly sample some good samples. But I wanted to keep all the bad samples. So I selected 8000 good samples and included all the 7000 bad samples. Thus, I had a 15,000 samples. I randomly splited them into training and testing data set. After training the decision tree on the training set, I fitted the testing data into the trained model, the result was vary promising.

However, I am really worried how this model would work on the entire population now. Although I compared the distribution conditioned on different variables for the good samples and good populations, the distribution of the good samples wasvery consistent with the good population.

Because the good samples and bad samples are equally weighted in the sampled data, the effect of the "BAD" is exaggerated in training the model, I am thinking that "BAD" will not be "BAD" if the entire data fit into the model, because the bad part is too tiny. do you think this is a potential failing issue for the model? Do you have any suggestions to fix this problem?

Comment: Did you try running random forests on the original data set?  If so, then what happened?  By augmenting the set of bad data, you effectively changed the behavior of your data set.

Comment: I did not run the random forests on the entire data set, because the data set was too large, I think the R will not be able to run this. Thanks for helping me on this. Do you have any thoughts that I can adjust the method or change the weight of the good/bad sample but keep the sample size?

Comment: Take a 1% random sample with no replacement of the 8 million points you have.  This would leave you with about 100K good/bad points and you could run random forests from a laptop.  Try this and then come back to this question.

Comment: Thanks Tim for the advice. I am trying this now.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen As you recommended, I rebuilt the decision tree model by using 1% of the good sample and all the bad samples. Then I used random forest. The result was promising. The classification error rate was only 1.23% on the test data set. However, there is one issue I am concerned. In the testing data, there are 24,783 good samples and 30 bad samples. The random forest classified 17 of the bad to be good samples, do you have any idea to decrease this number of classifying bad to be good? Thanks.

Comment: How many bad samples did you have in the 1% sample?  This is likely the reason for the misclassification.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I select the 1% data from the purely good samples, so there is no bad samples in the 1% data. Basically, I selected all the bad samples added together the 1% data to get my entire sample set.

Comment: I think you need to run random forests but use a 1% out of bag sample to build and test.  And please note that you _don't_ cross validate the output from _randomForest_.

Comment: How many trees did you use?  If you sample enough you should eventually use all the bad cases.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Do you mean that I should use all the good samples, but use 1% out of bag sample to build and test the random forest? I set mtry to be roughly equal to the square root of the number of my features, because this is a classification problem.

Comment: Let's take this offline.  Email me at TimBeagle@hotmail.com